# Datagrid slow when multiple row details have been expanded

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, rowdetails

So i have a datagrid, the contents of which are all populated from multiple web requests. The rowdetails, when expanded, also send multiple web requests to populate more information.

In the row details, there is a Listview, a listbox, a few layout elements, and some textblocks.

The datagrid scrolls fast after the initial data is added, but if you expand 4-5 row details, suddenly the scrolling is choppy to the point it is almost non existent.

Is this a known issue?

Can i reuse the same visual rowdetails element for each item? it is only shown when selected and all the data retrieved is cached so it wouldn't need to be reloaded on an element that has already been viewed

Rows are not expanded more than one at a time... The row details are only shown when an item is selected, and you can only select one at a time. The problem is that after you select a few different items, and the row detail visual objects are generated, it slows down.

Comment: In your Requirement, Is is Necessary to Expand More than one row at a time, if not then you can set at a Row expand mechanism on selection basis only.

Comment: See the addendum on the question

Comment: your performance slow down is also because of animation you have used and styles you have applied to your inner datagrid also.. so what you can try is that you can define style={x:null} in your child grid then can check the speed and performance. if it meets your expectation then its the issue with style applying. One more thing is that have you been ever used in UpdateLayout in your datagrid binding code then please remove it also.it will also make huge difference.

Comment: This was not the problem, see my answer

Comment: You can also use DeferredScrolling ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.isdeferredscrollingenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In the row details was this item:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=PreviewImageUrl, TargetNullValue=Collapsed}" />
```

PreviewImageUrl was null and for each row details item that was created/expanded, it would throw (and suppress) an Image converter exception while scrolling. That exception suppression is what was slowing the scrolling (as after expanding 10 row details, it would throw 10 exceptions on each scroll event).  As to why this happens I am still puzzled but at least I now know what to watch for!